# Where can I find the source code of builtin functions?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to study the source code of builtin functions of python. Where can I find the source code of these functions?

Thanks

Comment: In the Python repository...

Comment: Specifically Im looking for source of raw_input. Can you please point me right direction.